# Constructor executed when property get method executed

Tags: matlab, oop, inheritance

I'd like to subclass built-in controls such as `axes`; however, MATLAB doesn't allow this, as far as I can tell, in a documented way. To workaround this, I created a class called `MyAxes` shown below.

`MyAxes` has one defined property called `MATLABAxes` which stores a `matlab.graphics.axis.Axes` object. This axes object is created on construction. Each of the axes properties are added dynamically to the `MyAxes` object being constructed creating wrapper properties that should simply redirect to the `MATLABAxes` properties.

The get method for each of the wrapper properties is set to a method of `MyAxes` called `get_axes_property`. This method takes three arguments:

1. The `MyAxes` object itself
2. A reference to the axes control
3. The property name

This method works well except that it creates a new axes for each property. I end up with a figure that has 131 child axes! This seems to be happening because of the creation of the axes in the `MyAxes` constructor. A workaround this issue is to require that the MATLAB axes is created first and passed in as an argument to the constructor. This is rather inconvenient.

How do I maintain the axes creation in the `MyAxes` constructor without more than one axes being created? Of course, if I'm way off track and there's a better way to sub-class built-in controls, I'd love to hear about it.

```
classdef Axes < handle & dynamicprops

    properties
        MATLABAxes;
    end

    methods

        function obj = Axes
            obj.MATLABAxes = axes;
            axesPropertyList = properties( obj.MATLABAxes );
            for property = axesPropertyList(:)'
                propertyName = property{1};
                obj.addprop( propertyName );
                propertyInstance = obj.findprop( propertyName );
                propertyInstance.GetMethod = @(x,y)obj.get_axes_property( obj.MATLABAxes, propertyName );
            end
        end

        function value = get_axes_property( obj, control, propertyName )
            value = control.(propertyName);
        end

    end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Did it again - answered my own question while writing the question. It was a spelling mistake. I had put the first argument to the `get_axes_property` method in the function handle definition as `axes` instead of `obj.MATLABAxes`. This executed the `axes` function each time a property was gotten. The code in the question is now fixed.